# Eclipse Restore Project From Local History

Tags: eclipse

I deleted my .metadata file and ran eclipse and all files in my project became 0kb. I saw something about local history and I went into the folder and I saw a lot of folders and tried a few. I can find some of my files but there are so many versions of them. I cant import the project with 0kb weight so I couldnt acces local history from Eclipse Programm either. So my question is:
Is there a way ti restore a whole project from Local History? Or at least the files?

Thanks